# MySQL CHAR_LENGTH() alternative in IBM DB2

Tags: mysql, db2, functions, unicode

I have a value in a cell that has a Unicode character:

`"Nit€sh"`

I want to get the length in SB2. 
The problem is, If I use the length function it's considering `'€'` as 2 and total is 7. I am trying to achieve a total of 6 in this case.

**EXAMPLE**
In MySQL we had `char_length()` to address this.

**Is there anything similar in DB2?**

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0705nair/) explains how to deal with string lengths when Unicode characters are involved.

[`CHARACTER_LENGTH`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_characterlength.dita) is the function you need.

```
CHARACTER_LENGTH(yourstring,CODEUNITS32);
```